# Swift Out of Range when run Previous Function

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2

```
import GameKit

class FactModel {  // See, this is a class now.
    let facts = [ "Test1", "test2", "Test3", "test4", "Test5", "test6", "test7", "Test8", "test9", "test10", "Test11", "test12", "test13", "Test14", "test15", "test16", "Test17", "test18" ]
    var index = 0  // This is the property that will allow us to track what fact we are up to.

    func getRandomFact() -> String {  // No change to this method.
        let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(facts.count)

        return facts[randomNumber]
    }

    func getNextFact() -> String {
        let fact = facts[index]  // We grab the fact before we increment the index.
        if index < facts.count - 1 {  // We make sure we did not give the last fact in the list.
            index += 1  // We increment the index so the next fact is ready to go.
        } else {
            index = 0  // We wrap around to the first fact because we just gave the last one.
        }    
        return fact
    }

    func getPreviousFact() -> String {
        let fact = facts[index]
        if index < facts.count - 1{
            index -= 1
        } else {
            index = 0
        }
        return fact
    }
}

let myFact = FactModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the code line by line!

When `FactModel` is initialized, `index` is `0`. Now you call `getPreviousFact`:

line 1: `let fact = facts[index]`

Now, `fact` will be the first fact, i.e. Test1.

line 2: `if index < facts.count - 1{`

Is index less than `facts.count - 1`? It is! `index` is 0 and `facts.count - 1` is 17

line 3: `index -= 1`

Now, `index` is -1!

Therefore, the next time you call `getPreviousFact`, `let fact = facts[index]` is going to be run. Since `index` is now -1, it is out of range! :(

I think what you want is this:

```
    if index < facts.count && index > 0 {
        index -= 1
    } else {
        index = facts.count - 1
    }
```

This is just my guess, since you didn't mention what it is supposed to do when `index` is 0. So it might be different from your intended behaviour.

Comment: fine declaration! :-)

Comment: I'm getting an error. 1) Consecutive Declaration on the line must be separated whit ";"   2) When I put the Semi-Colon It says Expect a declaration

Comment: @Dani I edited the answer. If you still have errors, can you tell me which line(s) do the error occur on?

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks, but that code worked about a year ago.  I'll use it as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

u must first increase your index ant then retrieve the fact. And set the index this way:

```
func getPreviousFact() -> String {
    if index > facts.count {
        index -= 1
    } else {
        index = 0
    }
    let fact = facts[index]
    return fact
 }
```